# unable to connect docker mysql databse to codeigniter application

Tags: php, mysql, docker, codeigniter, ubuntu-18.04

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I have installed mysql server in docker. I am unable to connect mysql database to codeigniter project.

I have created mysqldb using following command

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_80 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -d mysql:8 mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

the database is running on docker. i am able to access via phpmyadmin.

**CONTAINER ID    IMAGE   COMMAND   CREATED STATUS   PORTS    NAMES
6c6474ed3f9d   mysql:8  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 seconds ago  Up 14 seconds       0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql_80**

This is my database.php

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '0.0.0.0:3306';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '1234';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['port']     = '3306'; 
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;    
$db['default']['failover'] = array();
$db['default']['save_queries'] = TRUE;
```

When i try to access codeigniter application i am getting following error:

**A Database Error Occurred**

**Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.**

**Filename: core/Loader.php**

**Line Number: 346**

I tried to access mysql db using terminal. i got an error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.

**Version**

**mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28 and 
php 7.2**

Thank you.

Comment: share us your docker compose file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '0.0.0.0:3306';
```

to:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1:3306';
```

0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address to connect, please note that I also supposed that your APP is running on the host directly not in a container

and change :

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_80 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -d mysql:8 mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

to :

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name mysql_80 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -d mysql:8 --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

you do not need to specify mysqld command since it is already the entrypoint in mysql image